# Hibernate doesn't auto create the tables but when the table is created, it inserts the values into the table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

If a table name employee is present already, this program updates the values into the database. If the table is not present, it doesn't create one and instead it gives the error message. someone kindly trouble shoot this. i'm not sure where i have the problem

```
hibernate.cfg.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->   
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/salarymanagement</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>

 <!-- JDBC connection pool -->  
 <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

 <!-- SQL dialect -->
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

 <!-- Disable the second level cache -->
 <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

 <!-- Echo all executed SQl to stdout-->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

 <!-- drop and re-create the database schema-->
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

<!-- Lists the annotated entity class -->
<mapping class="com.Hibernate.Employee"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

MainClass

```
package com.Hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class EmployeeExecution 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Employee e1 = new Employee(1,"sri",27,30000);
 SessionFactory sessionfactory = new 
 Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(e1);
session.getTransaction().commit();
}

}
```

POJO Class

```
package com.Hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity 
public class Employee 
{
@Id
private int id;
private String name;
private int age;
private int salary;


public Employee(int id, String name, int age, int salary) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
}
```

Error message

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1441)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:491)
at 

org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3201)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at com.Hibernate.EmployeeExecution.main(EmployeeExecution.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3003)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3503)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1435)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'salarymanagement.employee' doesn't exist
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:115)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:1983)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1826)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2034)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5001)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1955)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205)
    ... 18 more
00:52:26.579 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - Connection pool now considered primed; min-size will be maintained
```

Comment: Change to update and see `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Comment: it's still giving the same error

Answer (score 2):

hibernate.cfg.xml file

---

`

          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

```
<session-factory>  

    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems</property>

    <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  

    <mapping class="com.scs.model.Employee1" />



</session-factory>
```

`

Employee.java
`@Entity
public class Employee1 {

```
@Id
private int id; 
private String name;
private int age;
private int salary;


public Employee1(int id, String name, int age, int salary) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.salary = salary;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}
public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}
```

}
`

Main.java

`public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String arg[]){

        //Creating Configuration file
        Configuration cfg = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();

        //opening session
        Session session = cfg.buildSessionFactory().openSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Employee1 emp1 = new Employee1(1,"sri",27,30000); 

        session.persist(emp1);

        transaction.commit();
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please Try This

`<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>`

Comment: OP added in that `xml ` actually

Comment: Yes it does in your case because of the below property in your config. This is ok during testing but in production you need to disable this.
<br>
'<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>'

Comment: when i changed to
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
it displays error in 
<session-factory> tag in hiberbate.cfg.xml file

Comment: what do you mean by op added in that xml?